# Owning slaves today

Tags: slavery

Assalamu alaikum,

In the course of my readings, I have often wondered whether, nowadays, there are still areas of the Muslim world (whether in the Gulf or the Maghreb etc) where people still actually own Shar'i slaves unofficially, and also whether it is still possible to procure them.

Obviously I'm not talking about modern slaves such as migrants and forced laborers where this does not at all respect fiqh and Shar'ia related to slavery.

Barak Allahu fikoum for your answers.